# Qt 5.7 Signals/Slots fof Producer-Consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I can not find anywhere in the Qt 5.7 documentation of signals and slots if they can be used as a "replacement" for the Producer-Consumer problem.

On a thread, data is constantly being generated and the second thread catches all this data, use it and save the result in a text file. Is it safe to use Signals/Slots here with `Qt:QueuedConnection` where it is really **important** to process data in same order as they come.

How does Qt deal with this kind of connection internally?

Comment: Events are queued in order, so you are guaranteed that if thread A emits signal 1 then signal 2, then thread B will receive them in the same order.  No guarantees can be made for the ordering in thread B of signals emitted by threads A and C, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Qt signals and slots are usually thread safe to use. I'm pretty sure there is a good documentation about it, try this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/signalsandslots.html and here for for more info about thread interconnectivity with sigals and slots: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

Comment: It is clear that they are thread-safe but I just can not find how is this implemented and if I can use it for the described problem.

Comment: since the connection is queued I think the order will be maintained, like first in first out (that's like a definition of a queue). if you really want to verify that you can write a simple programm or look at the Qt source code and find the implementation!? http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel (there are the qobject source files), maybe that will help: static void queued_activate http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#n3545